# Not getting access to Windows SpatialPerception for Immersive VR

Tags: azure, unity-game-engine, uwp, windows-mixed-reality, azure-spatial-anchors

I am developing in Unity for the new HP Reverb building on UWP. I would like to use Azure Spatial Anchors to share those anchors between computers.

Since the HP Reverb is an InsideOut tracked Headset, the Spatial Anchors are working fine, but I am not getting access to the SpatialAnchorExporter. Using the [Azure Example Project](https://github.com/Azure/azure-spatial-anchors-samples) for connecting to the cloud from Unity gives me an `Access denied to spatial anchor exporter.` error.

**In "Capabilities" I have SpatialPerception ENABLED**, I checked it in Unity AND in VS2019.

Specifically the following lines which tell me that I have no access:

```
Windows.Perception.Spatial.SpatialPerceptionAccessStatus accessStatus = 
await Windows.Perception.Spatial.SpatialAnchorExporter.RequestAccessAsync();
```

Trying to do the same thing without Azure gives me more or less the same error, `UnityEngine.XR.WSA.Sharing.WorldAnchorTransferBatch.ExportAsync()` returns:

```
SpatialAnchorTransferManager denied access to WorldAnchor serialization 
UnityEngine.XR.WSA.Sharing.WorldAnchorTransferBatch:ExportAsync_Internal(WorldAnchorTransferBatch, 
SerializationDataAvailableDelegate, SerializationCompleteDelegate) 
UnityEngine.XR.WSA.Sharing.WorldAnchorTransferBatch:ExportAsync(WorldAnchorTransferBatch, 
SerializationDataAvailableDelegate, SerializationCompleteDelegate)
```

Comment: I noticed that you have post the same issue on GitHub(https://github.com/microsoft/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/issues/6210), and the PG believes the device might not  support this feature. Since this is a Unity API, I suggest you file this as an issue to Unity Communtiy. They may be faster to find a solution or understand what's wrong.

Comment: [Q Unity Forums](https://forum.unity.com/threads/exporting-world-anchors-returns-access-denied.755351/)
Have asked there too. The reverb has basically almost the same tracking as the HoloLens, and from what I know, Azure Spatial Anchors have been used with Immersive headsets before...

Comment: Also: Windows.Perception.Spatial.SpatialAnchorExporter.RequestAccessAsync() is part of the UWP Api, the unity XR.WSA namespace just links in there afaik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the HP Reverb usage scenario raised on saving spatial anchors, this is not available.   This WorldAnchorTransferBatch API is exposed for HoloLens at this point solely.

That said, Microsoft has provided specific support and guidance for LBE(Location based entertainment) usage. Specifically, we have documented the ability to importing and exporting of the map. Microsoft has also provided tools to export the configurations to multiple immersive headset devices. See [LBE-MULTI-PLAYER SETUP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/location-based-experiences#multi-player-setup)

Comment: thanks a bunch for the response! May I ask though, why that API is not exposed for VR HMD's with inside-out tracking? Or generally, why is no spatial perception capability exposed for inside out tracking devices?

Comment: For the spatial perception Windows API and exporting of anchors, that is handled in the SpatialAnchorExporter.GetAnchorExportSufficiencyAsync API.   The support for exporting was made back in 2016 when HoloLens was the only inside-out tracking device for Windows. If the device is running Windows, this  API support is there still just for HoloLens.  You can ask for features to be added to Windows with the feedback hub application.  Here is the direct link for [Mixed Reality feedback hub suggestions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/hololens/hololens-feedback)